# position elements after statically positioned div with no specified height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

JSFiddle Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/e2h6cwu9/

```
<section id="mainContainer">
        <!-- Dashboard Section -->
        <div class="dashboard">
            <div class="gridster">
                <ul>
                    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>PROJECT LOAD PER PERSON</h1></li>
                    <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>RTN LOAD PER PERSON</h1></li>
                    <li data-row="1" data-col="3" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>TICKET LOAD PER PERSON</h1></li>

                    <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>RTN LIFESPAN PER PERSON</h1></li>
                    <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>TICKET LIFESPAN PER PERSON</h1></li>
                    <li data-row="2" data-col="3" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2"><h1>UNTOUCHED FOR 7 DAYS</h1></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Projects Section -->
        <div class="projects">
            <span>PROJECT STUFF</span>
        </div>

        <!-- RTNs Section -->
        <div class="rtns">
            <span>RTN STUFF</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Tickets Section -->
        <div class="tickets">
            <span>TICKET STUFF</span>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <span>This needs to fall under the gridster </span>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I am attempting to put content under my .gridster DIV, but since its parent DIV .dashboard has no height, and my #mainContainer section has position static with no height, that the gridster DIV also has no height?  How do I make the #footer div fall under the .gridster DIV without assigning a specified height to the wrapper?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gridster automatically sets the height of its `ul` to do exactly what you're asking, but you're overriding that with your rule

```
.gridster ul {
   list-style: none;
   height: auto !important;
   width: 100% !important;
   display: block;
}
```

If you delete `height: auto !important;`, you're all set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I really appreciate the help!  So, if I remove the     height: auto !important, then gridster drag-and-drop function stops working...  Any idea why that could be?  It still functions in IE11 fine, but in Chrome 50.0.2661.94, it's a no go on the drag-and-drop of gridster.

Comment: Yep, it works in IE11 because IE is terrible at handling z-indexes properly. Chrome is doing what it's supposed to do. You have this line: `.gridster {
    width: 1600px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 125px;
    z-index: -100;
}`. If you remove `z-index: -100`, it should behave as expected

Comment: Thanks jmcgriz!  I really appreciate the help!!